# Google Sign in Error 12500 SHA1 double checked GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

Tags: java, android, google-signin

I am getting this error after selecting a google account. OnActivityResult is called, but after evaluating the result this error is thrown. The cause is not a wrong SHA1, I am using the same key for release and debug. The app is not from Google Play. I am not using firebase. The google signin sample works with the same key.

com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500:

Stacktrace:

```
W/System.err: com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12500: 
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.ApiExceptionUtil.fromStatus(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(Unknown Source)
W/System.err:     at de.org.limindo.limindo2.fragLogin.onActivityResult(fragLogin.java:412)
W/System.err:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:151)
W/System.err:     at de.org.limindo.limindo2.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:788)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3549)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3596)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code is:

```
           GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(fragLogin.this._main, gso);


mSignInGoogle0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

            }
        });

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // The Task returned from this call is always completed, no need to attach
        // a listener.
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}


private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        if (account != null)
        {
            mPasswordView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mPasswordView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        updateUI(account);
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
        lib.ShowMessage(getContext(), getString(R.string.googleloginnotsuccessfull) + "\n" + getString(R.string.ErrorCode) + GoogleSignInStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(e.getStatusCode()) + ":" + e.getStatusCode(), getString(R.string.Error));
        updateUI(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: have you setup project in developer console and enabled relative apis?

Comment: You mean api console?

Comment: How do I enable relative apis? I have this project in api console, but I don't find relative apis......

Comment: check this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating

Comment: I used exactly this page for setting up my project... But it doesn't work!

Comment: Is it not working perhaps because I didn't enable payment?

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anybody: I was in this situation, except that it worked initially then stopped working later. I finally realized that it was because I switched laptops.

Comment: As for why it took me so long to realize this: I just never re-used the login feature until months after changing laptops.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the package name: The package name of the manifest is de.org.limindo.limindo2 but the package of the apk is de.org.limindo2 ..... It seems that gradle shortens package names, if they contain double entries….